# XLS VBA VlookUp using RC from static to dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a MACRO for a vlook-up.

I have 2 sheets. I managed to make it work with VlookUp hardcoded.

Can i make it dynamic?

Here is my code :

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub VlookUp4()

    Dim NrColsOld, NrColsNew As Integer 'Numarul de celule in primul rand, incepand cu A1 sheet "old" si "new"
    Dim FoundOld, FoundNew As Range
    Dim LROld, LRNew As Long
    Dim Cauta As Variant
    'Cauta = InputBox("Filtru dupa ce coloana?")

    Sheets("old").Select
    With ActiveSheet
        NrColsOld = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Calculeaza care e ultima coloana din sheet
    End With
    'Set Found = Rows(1).Find(What:=Cauta, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FoundOld = Rows(1).Find(What:="Numar", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If FoundOld Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    LROld = Cells(Rows.Count, FoundOld.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LROld, FoundOld.Column + NrColsOld)).AutoFilter
    Worksheets("old").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LROld, FoundOld.Column + NrColsOld)).Columns.AutoFit
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LROld, NrColsOld)).Select 'selecteaza celulele ce contin valori
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("old").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(1, FoundOld.Column), Cells(1, FoundOld.Column)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    'Range(Cells(1, Found.Column), Cells(1, Found.Column)).Select   'selecteaza doar celula cu numele celulei dupa care facem ordonarea
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("old").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    Sheets("new").Select
    With ActiveSheet
        NrColsNew = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Calculeaza care e ultima coloana din sheet
    End With
    'Set Found = Rows(1).Find(What:=Cauta, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FoundNew = Rows(1).Find(What:="Numar", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If FoundNew Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    LRNew = Cells(Rows.Count, FoundNew.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + NrColsNew)).AutoFilter
    Worksheets("new").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + NrColsNew)).Columns.AutoFit
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRNew, NrColsNew + 1)).Select 'selecteaza celulele ce contin valori + 1 se adauga pentru ca se insereaza o coloana
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("new").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(1, FoundNew.Column), Cells(1, FoundNew.Column)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    'Range(Cells(1, Found.Column), Cells(1, Found.Column)).Select   'selecteaza doar celula cu numele celulei dupa care facem ordonarea
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("new").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    FoundNew.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    Cells(1, FoundNew.Column + 1).Value = "New vs Old"

    Dim unu, doi, trei As Integer
    unu = 1
    doi = 2
    trei = 3

    Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],old!C[-3]:C[-2],2,0)"
    'Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-unu],old!C[-trei]:C[-doi],2,0)"
'    Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).Select
'    Selection.Copy
'    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'    Selection.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="Intrari Noi", lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
'    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Intrari Noi"
End Sub
```

First i want to transform

```
Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],old!C[-3]:C[-2],2,0)"
```

into

```
Dim unu, doi, trei As Integer
    unu = 1
    doi = 2
    trei = 3


   Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-unu],old!C[-trei]:C[-doi],2,0)"
```

Can anyone give me a hint please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your into statement to:

```
Dim unu, doi, trei As Integer
    unu = 1
    doi = 2
    trei = 3


   Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & unu & "],old!C[-" & trei & "]:C[-" & doi & "],2,0)"
```

**Explanation:** If you attempted to use the code as you presented it, VBA would interpret `unu`, `doi`, and `trei` as the literal strings they represent, and you will end up with `=VLOOKUP(RC[-unu],old!C[-trei]:C[-dui],2,0)` in your cell, which Excel won't know what to do with.

When you concatenate them into the `vlookup` string via the `&`, VBA is able to pass the values of the variables `unu` (1), `doi` (2), and `trei` (3) into the `vlookup` string. So you get `=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],old!C[-3]:C[-2],2,0)` in your cell instead, and Excel can work with that.

Comment: For those of you who may might need somthing like this, here is the full code :

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit

Sub VlookUp4()

```
Dim NrColsOld, NrColsNew As Integer 'Numarul de celule in primul rand, incepand cu A1 sheet "old" si "new"
Dim FoundOld, FoundNew As Range
Dim LROld, LRNew As Long
Dim Cauta As Variant
Dim Coloana1, Coloana2, Coloana3, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 As String

Coloana1 = "Numar"
Coloana2 = "Valoare"
Coloana3 = "New vs Old"
Sheet1 = "old"
Sheet2 = "new"
Sheet3 = "new vs old"

'Enter = InputBox("Filtru dupa ce coloana?")

Sheets(Sheet1).Select
With ActiveSheet
    NrColsOld = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Calculeaza care e ultima coloana din sheet
End With
'Set Found = Rows(1).Find(What:=Enter, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set FoundOld = Rows(1).Find(What:=Coloana1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If FoundOld Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
LROld = Cells(Rows.Count, FoundOld.Column).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LROld, NrColsOld)).AutoFilter
Worksheets(Sheet1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LROld, FoundOld.Column + NrColsOld)).Columns.AutoFit
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LROld, NrColsOld)).Select 'selecteaza celulele ce contin valori
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(1, FoundOld.Column), Cells(1, FoundOld.Column)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'Range(Cells(1, Found.Column), Cells(1, Found.Column)).Select   'selecteaza doar celula cu numele celulei dupa care facem ordonarea
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


Sheets(Sheet2).Select
With ActiveSheet
    NrColsNew = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Calculeaza care e ultima coloana din sheet
End With
'Set Found = Rows(1).Find(What:=Cauta, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set FoundNew = Rows(1).Find(What:=Coloana1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If FoundNew Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
LRNew = Cells(Rows.Count, FoundNew.Column).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRNew, NrColsNew)).AutoFilter
Worksheets(Sheet2).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + NrColsNew)).Columns.AutoFit
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRNew, NrColsNew + 1)).Select 'selecteaza celulele ce contin valori + 1 se adauga pentru ca se insereaza o coloana
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet2).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(1, FoundNew.Column), Cells(1, FoundNew.Column)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'Range(Cells(1, Found.Column), Cells(1, Found.Column)).Select   'selecteaza doar celula cu numele celulei dupa care facem ordonarea
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet2).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
FoundNew.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Cells(1, FoundNew.Column + 1).Value = Coloana3

Dim resOldx, resNewx, resNewy As Object
Dim CC, GetColumnNumber, GetColumnNumberOldx, GetColumnNumberNewx, GetColumnNumberNewy As Integer

'############################
Set resOldx = Sheets(Sheet1).Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Coloana1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
If resOldx Is Nothing Then
    GetColumnNumberOldx = 0
Else
    GetColumnNumberOldx = resOldx.Column
End If
'MsgBox ("Numar Old " & GetColumnNumberOldx)

'############################
Set resNewy = Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Coloana1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
If resNewy Is Nothing Then
    GetColumnNumberNewy = 0
Else
    GetColumnNumberNewy = resNewy.Column
End If
'MsgBox ("Numar New " & GetColumnNumberNewy)

'############################
Set resNewx = Sheets(Sheet2).Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=Coloana3, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
If resNewx Is Nothing Then
    GetColumnNumberNewx = 0
Else
    GetColumnNumberNewx = resNewx.Column
End If
'MsgBox ("New vs Old " & GetColumnNumberNewx)

CC = GetColumnNumberNewx


Dim x, y, z As Integer

x = GetColumnNumberNewy - GetColumnNumberNewx
'MsgBox ("x are valoarea " & x)
y = GetColumnNumberOldx - GetColumnNumberNewx
'MsgBox ("y are valoarea " & y)
z = 0
'MsgBox ("z are valoarea " & z)

Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & x & "],old!C[" & y & "]:C[" & z & "],1,0)"
Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="Intrari Noi", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, FoundNew.Column + 1), Cells(LRNew, FoundNew.Column + 1)).AutoFilter field:=CC, Criteria1:="Intrari Noi"
Worksheets(Sheet2).Columns.AutoFit

Range("A2").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
   .TintAndShade = 0
End With

Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(Sheet3).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets(Sheet3).Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub

Comment: you can compare 2 sheets an ol version and a new one.

Comment: I compare data from this mounth with the data from last month and extract automaticaly the new entries.